# Is it possible to automatically rerun Databricks Job Clusters

Tags: azure-databricks

I have a job cluster that I would like to rerun when it reaches the end of the notebook - is that possible?

For example, lets say my Databricks notebook ends with the following code.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([json.dumps(result)])
spark.read.json(rdd) \
  .write.mode("overwrite").json('/mnt/lake/RAW/FormulaClassification/F1Area/')
```

Under normal circumstances, when the job cluster has successfully completed all the cells in the notebook without any failures the job cluster would end and provide a status notification saying 'Succeeded'.

I would like the notebook to re-run straight after the notification - and run indefinitely?

Is that possible?

Or is it even possible to keep a cluster just up and running indefinitely, with it just sitting there waiting for up and coming executions (I hope the last sentence makes sense). I guess what I'm trying to say is that once a Job cluster is running I don't want it to terminate unless I physically terminate it.

Comment: please add more information on what do you want to achieve? What kind of processing do you need

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for reaching out. This is a little tricky to explain. But basically, my Databricks notebooks are largely based on parameters or variables being inserted automatically via Data Factory or may be SQL. Therefore, a single notebook can be run multiple times. But in normal operation, after each run of a notebook, it closes down and runs the same notebook again. and in that operation, the cluster shuts down and needs to spun up for another run of the notebook. I need a method of ensuring the cluster remains up all the time. I thought this could be achieved using job clusters

Answer (score 0):

You can opt out of auto termination by clearing the Auto Termination checkbox or by specifying an inactivity period of 0.

[image]

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/clusters-manage#configure-automatic-termination

Comment: it will be more expensive to run jobs on the interactive cluster

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this would be to use a loop in your notebook that implements some kind of logic to check if there is anything to do.

```
import time
while (true):
  if (isNewDataAvailable):
    dbutils.notebook.run("/path/to/notebook")
  time.sleep(10)
```

If you use autoscale for your cluster then it should scale down to one node while sleeping saving costs.